# My MS AD server hangs without any information

Tags: active-directory, hangs

At Random times my Microsoft AD Server gets totally frozen (but i can see that the cursor moves freely and num lock status is also fine but on the screen i dont see anything other than the background). I dont see any error in the event viewer other than ntfrs error/warning in the File Replication. Not sure why this is happening. The only option left is to turn it down manually using the power button and then restart. Kindly let me know if any additional information required. Kindly help.

Comment: We probably need way more information then you've provided here.  What version of Windows Server?  What hardware is this server?  What is the specific eventid for the FRS errors?  Are people able to logon when it's "frozen"?  If not, what errors are the users getting?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Dear Greg, It is MS server 2003 Enterprise installed on a Dell PowerEdge 1800 (Intel Xeon 3Ghz, 2Gb RAM, 80GB HDD). The Event ID for FRS Warning/Errors are 13520, 13565, 13509, 13508, 13560, 13561, 13568). Once the server is frozen. People will not be able to login, which means no internet (as the internet authentication happens through AD), WiFi... basically all the services linked to AD wont work until i reboot the server. This problem is totally killing my life. When ever the server is down. I had to go to office and reboot to resume the services. This is happening at random times. plz help

Comment: and also... the FRS errors exist from the year 2006 itself but we never had this problem. One thing that i have noticed, before the server is frozen... all the services slow down... login takes time... network shared drives take time to open... internet authentication takes time and then it is totally frozen/unresponsive.

Comment: so this was working all along then recently went bad or have you been fighting this awhile.

Comment: yes it was working without any problem before. It all started 2 months ago and continuing... Not really sure what's causing the problem.

Comment: and strangely the Ethernet is always alive even after the server is frozen coz i get a ping response. Someone plz add some light to the problem.

Comment: were any patches applied

Comment: Finally... changing the motherboard solved the issue. i Am in peace at last...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally... changing the motherboard solved the issue. i Am in peace at last...

Comment: Please mark this answer as accepted so that others can find it in the future, and it comes off your unaccepted list.

Answer (score 0):

You've got two problems here.  FRS replication is one thing, which is unlikely to be related to the server hanging.

There should be some specific management software from Dell that is for that server -  I forget what it's called.  If you haven't got that on there, install it and keep an eye on the logs.  If you have got it installed, make sure it is up to date and make sure all the drivers and firmware are up to date too.

Comment: Robin, I have already installed Dell DSET Report Tool and generated the report and sent it to Dell. They say that there are no issues with the hardware or the Software. It is totally confusing on to what is causing this issue.

Comment: Finally... changing the motherboard solved the issue. i Am in peace at last...

Answer (score 0):

Could be something is memory leaking up to the point of the lockup. You can
use Task Manager and or Performance Monitor to see what is consuming the
mem/ cpu. A consistently positive "Mem Delta" value may indicates a memory
leak.

Also verify MSConfig to check if there any startup services (Silent Malware) are marked ON.

Check your list of installed programs in control panel "Programs" and find if there any worthless application is installed.

Comment: i did check all of the things mentioned above. There seems to be something else...

Comment: Finally... changing the motherboard solved the issue. i Am in peace at last...